# Firefox does not support the <code> tag?

Tags: html, firefox, tags

I tried using the `<code>` tag, but Firefox does not seem to recognize it, although it is a very old tag. It renders it just as flowable plaintext. Why is this?

Here is an example:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <title>Test code tag</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    Here is some code:
        <code>
~: which vim
/usr/bin/vim

Note that vi, the old text editor on which Vim is based, is redirected via a symbolic link on most modern Linux systems:

~: which vi
/usr/bin/vi

~: ls -l /usr/bin/vi
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 20 Sep 18  2013 /usr/bin/vi -> /etc/alternatives/vi

~: ls -l /etc/alternatives/vi
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 18 Feb 14  2014 /etc/alternatives/vi -> /usr/bin/vim.basic
        </code>
    </body>
</html>
```

In the latest version of Firefox the code in the sample above is flowed with no line breaks.

Comment: We need to see your actual code.

Comment: Are there any style rules applied to this tag?  Does the same effect happen on other browsers?

Comment: Are you using a css reset which might set the style for code?

Comment: @Dai I added a minimal example

Comment: `<code>` is for inline code, not for blocks of code, use `<pre>` for that.